# Tomcat 9+: overriding Servlet mapping using @WebServlet annotation

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat9

Which is the precedence order of `@WebServlet` annotation vs `web.xml` servlet mapping?
More specifically we've a use case where we would rather not modify the `web.xml` but would need to override one of the servlet mappings.
Our `web.xml` has something like:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.whatever.simple.foo</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And we are considering overriding this using:

```
@WebServlet("/foo/*")
public class OurCustomImplementation extends HttpServlet {
}
```

So the question is:

- is the specification allowing us to add some parameter to do so (e.g. override or prioriry parameters)?
- is the specification *guaranting* that our class will always override `web.xml`?
- Will Tomcat 9+ allow to do it, even if maybe using some extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Servlet 3.1 Final and 4.0.Final specs say in 12.2 Specification of Mappings:

> If the effective web.xml (after merging information from fragments and
> annotations) contains any url-patterns that are mapped to multiple servlets then the deployment must fail.

So the spec clearly doesn't allow this.

Alternative solution: create a WebFilter that does a forward dispatch to another url, that your overriding servlet handles. Or just do your thing in the filter itself.

Comment: the @WebFilter option worked for our purposes